# sshd does not pick up authorized keys file when attaching a new /home partition on GCP

Tags: ssh, redhat, google-cloud-platform, partition

I need to create a RHEL machine on GCP with separate partitions for /home, /tmp, and /var. If I were installing on a physical machine I would simply partition my disk when I install the OS but I can't seem to figure this out on a GCP virtual machine. I:

- instantiated a new RHEL VM on GCP by selecting an existing one and the "create similar" feature
- created a new disk on GCP with `gcloud compute disks create acas-home  --size 200 --type pd-ssd`
- attached it to my VM with `gcloud compute instances attach-disk <my-vm-name> --disk acas-home`
- formatted it with `sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/sdb`
- mounted the new partition just once in a temporary folder and copied the original .ssh folder into to to import the authorized_keys file
- added the new disk to /etc/fstab with the following line `UUID=<MY_UUID_VALUE> /home ext4 discard,defaults,nofail 0 2`
- mounted the disks with `sudo mount -a`
- restarted sshd with `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`

After this, I cannot ssh into the server. I tried simply deleting the authorized_keys file and creating a new one but nothing would do. I also tried adding another authorized keys file to sshd_config, and populating it, with this line but it would not pick it up either:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions for the directory `~/.ssh` and the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If the settings are wrong, you cannot log in with that user ID.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue ? Can you connect via SSH at all ? You may also try [serial console interactive mode](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console). Have a look at my other answer on [how to connect if you lost access](https://serverfault.com/a/1045717/545593).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcloud) and make the connection through gcloud:

```
gcloud compute ssh --project=PROJECT_ID --zone=ZONE VM_NAME
```

You can find more guidance in the official documentation on how to [troubleshoot SSH in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to restore the SELinux contexts for your newly created partition.

```
restorecon -rv /home
```